# How do I convert a version into a string without version in azure pipelines?

Tags: python, azure-pipelines

I do have some python version parameters which look like below:

```
parameters:
  pythonVersions: [2.7, 3.7, 3.6, 3.5]
```

During matrix expansing I do `python.version: ${{ version }}` but later I need to be able to compose the string `py27` from `python.version` but I was not able to find documentation on how to perform the conversion.

Doing `py$(python.version)` gets my py2.7 and I need to get rid of the dot. I also trying to index [0] but it is not supported.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

fairly certain there is nothing built-in that can help you, you can use a script step and do some sed magic or something similar to sed and then "export" the result, here's an example I'm using:

```
- bash: |
    date=$(date --rfc-3339=ns | sed "s/ /T/; s/\(\....\).*-/\1-/g")
    echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=CONTAINER_BUILD_TIME]$date"
```

then, you can use `$(CONTAINER_BUILD_TIME)` in subsequent steps to access the variable you've set in the script step

Comment: ... and it could have being so easy wit jinja2. I am going to try the hack now. THanks.

Comment: sorry, there was a typo in the answer, fixed it